# Функция автозагрузки классов

Tags: php

spl_autoload_register — Регистрирует заданную функцию в качестве реализации метода __autoload()

Смотрим [исходники Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php#L594)

```
spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit$suffix', 'loadClassLoader'), true, $prependAutoloader);
self::\$loader = \$loader = new \\Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader();
spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit$suffix', 'loadClassLoader'));
```

Они массив передают а не функцию... Или там массив функций?

Comment: Так `array('ComposerAutoloaderInit$suffix', 'loadClassLoader')` передается ссылка на метод `loadClassLoader` класса `ComposerAutoloaderInit$suffix` P.S. Пример номер 4 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: [Посмотрите интерфейс  callable](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php)